# How to find simultaneous eigenstates for multiple non-commuting Hermitian operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra

Basic quantum mechanics told us that multiple commuting Hermitian operators have simultaneous eigenstates (as a **complete basis** for the Hilbert space). However, there are cases where the operator are non-commuting while they share **some** eigenstates (the number of which is less than the dimension of Hilbert space and do not form a complete basis). My question is: is there a general algorithm to find (or check if there is any) simultaneous eigenstates for multi (not necessarily commuting) operators?

Comment: Sorry this is not clear or I’m misreading something.  In general, non-commuting operators do NOT share eigenstates so why should there be a general algorithm to find states that in general do not exist?

Comment: Regarding your first sentence, basic QM tells you a bit more: [Q,Q']=0 iff Q and Q' have a basis of joint eigenstates which simultaneously diagonalize them.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Sorry for the inaccurate statement. I agree that in general non-commuting operators do not share eigenstates. What I want the algorithm to do is to check if the operators have common eigenstates and return eigenstates if they do.

Comment: @A.Bordg Yes, I agree with the simultaneously diagonalization condition. While two non-commuting operators do not share a complete eigenstates basis, they may have **some** (the number is less than the dimension of the Hilbert space) common eigenstates in special cases. I am interested in identifying these cases and find the shared eigenstates.

Comment: maybe you could provide an example of what you have in mind.

Comment: All simultaneous eigenvectors of two operators $A, B \colon V \to V$ will be contained in the kernel of the commutator $[A, B]$. So such an algorithm could be to compute the eigenspaces of $A$ and the kernel of $[A, B]$, then take the intersection of each eigenspace with that kernel.